# How to convert <class 'bytes'> data in tuple in python?

Tags: python, byte

to convert <class 'bytes'> data in tuple in python?
example:

```
data = b'["1","2","3"]'
data = tuple(data)
print(data)
output:(91, 34, 49, 34, 44, 34, 50, 34, 44, 34, 51, 34, 93)
```

But i need output like below.
Expected output:

```
data = (1,2,3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't know how is `encoded` the original string of bytes.

Suppose they are in json:

```
import json
tuple(json.loads(data))

#('1', '2', '3')
```

If they (unfortunately) are a py representation:

```
tuple(eval(data))

#('1', '2', '3')
```

The main question is, how are they encoded in a string?

Answer (score 1):

One approach is first to decode the byte-string then use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to convert it to list:

```
from ast import literal_eval

data = b'["1","2","3"]'
res = literal_eval(data.decode("utf-8"))
res = tuple(res)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
('1', '2', '3')
```